# Information about "128.242.245.20", possible twitter server?

Tags: php, twitter, curl

Currently working on a legacy script  (PHP) for one of my customers. 
He just called me telling, that I somehow messed up his script.

I narrowed the problems down to a completely different portion of the source. 
Seems as if the script is trying to post something on twitter. 
The server is hard coded to

```
http://128.242.245.20/statuses/update.xml?status=[someDynamicallyAddedString]
```

The server does not seem to be online, i.e. it does not react to either HTTP or Ping.

Does anyone have any information about this server or whether the way to publish on twitter changed recently?

Comment: Looking up IPs != programming

Comment: Indeed, I should have put the emphasis on "recent changes to twitter API". I stand corrected

Comment: Cheers. It's still off-topic, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this source](http://www.robtex.com/ip/128.242.245.20.html), `128.242.245.20` is a legacy server used by twitter indeed. Seems to me like a regular attempt to call the Twitter API, so to make it work, changing the IP to `twitter.com` should do it.

Comment: thx, Alex. Already did this on my way out. Seems to work again.

Comment: Not just `twitter.com`, but rather  `http://api.twitter.com/[version]/` http://dev.twitter.com/doc/post/statuses/update

Answer (score 0):

Using a geolocator it seems it is owned by Verio Inc. Which is a hosting provider.
Doesn't seem to be directly related to Twitter.

Answer (score 0):

You should never bind directly to an IP as DNS constantly changes, the company might have geo locking or they may route you to the closest server etc.

The IP could be bound to one server where as x.example.com could be bound to a multitude of ips i.e. round-robin or maybe nlb.

OK gonna stop having an rant :P, just saying its always better to bind to an fqdn hostname, the extra few milliseconds on the lookup will be worth it.

Comment: I do know that. Tell it to the smart ass who had this idea initially :-)